# Could anyone give me a hand on the render :update in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, renderpartial

well, could anyone give me some support doc for render :update method
until now i've only know about the page.alert method and page.replace_html method.

Here my testing code.

```
render :update do |page|
  page.alert(get_notice_str)
  page.replace_html "tr_01", :partial => 'goods', :object => goods
end
```

luckly it works fine.

now, i got a test function like set the disabled button true for the page, but i've no idea which method could help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done like this:

```
render :update do |page|
  page << "$('#elem').attr('disabled', 'true')" # or any JS you want
end
```

Answer (score 2):

1. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html
2. http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render
3. http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-talk/browse_thread/thread/d5e7fb7347e641be